# Magento getAddToCartUrl - not working with query string ampersand

Tags: magento

The following Code works fine in most cases - except if you call it from a search URL ( www.mysite.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=0&q=searchproductname ) .

```
<button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

In the above case , it adds to cart - but it changes the URL to an encoded form of :

www.mysite.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=0&q=searchproductname

It is basically encoding the ampersand by the looks .. how do I prevent this?

Comment: Check   if($_product->isSaleable()):

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for button on click

```
<button class="button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```